# How to add update a table with new data

Tags: python, postgresql-9.5

I have written query to add data to a DB but would like to add more data without dropping the DB every time. How do I go about writing such query?

**what I have:**

```
category = (
    (1, 'Sports'),
    (2, 'Entertainment'),
    (3, 'Politics'),
    (4, 'Technology'),
    (5, 'Health'),
    (6, 'Business'),
    (7, 'Travel Competition'),)

query2 = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users_category (Id, Name) VALUES (%s, %s)
cursor.executemany(query2, category)
```

**what I've tried:**

```
category = (
    (1, 'Sports'),
    (2, 'Entertainment'),
    (3, 'Politics'),
    (4, 'Technology'),
    (5, 'Health'),
    (6, 'Business'),
    (7, 'Travel'),
    (8, 'Other'),) #new data

query2 = "INSERT INTO users_category (Id, Name) VALUES (%s, %s) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET Name = excluded.users_category.Name"
```

**Error Traceback:**

```
Error invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table 
"users_category"
LINE 1: ... 'Sports') ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET Name = 
excluded.u...
                                                         ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "users_category", but it cannot be 
referenced from this part of the query.
```

**Desired Result:**

A script to add more data to an existing table without the need for flushing the previous data manually.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
query2 = "INSERT INTO users_category (Id, Name) VALUES (%s, %s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
```